# Adding degrees to a square shape

Tags: sketch-app, isometric

I'm trying to create an isometric cube, but I don't know how to add 30º to a square shape. Is it possible in Sketch App?

[image]

Comment: I'm not a Sketch user, but there certainly must be a **Skew** option somewhere.. which is what this is called.

Comment: @Scott Last time i used sketch it didnt have a skew option. But ist available as a plugin. No there must not be anything,

Comment: Actually @joojaa according to the documentation, there is... [**SEE HERE**](https://www.sketch.com/docs/shapes/#how-to-edit-shapes-using-the-transform-tool) This may also answer your question, Bruno.

Comment: Another option instead of skewing is to perhaps use an isometric grid, and draw your shapes with the pen tool to snap to the grid.  I'm not a sketch user either, so I don't know how practical this suggestion is, but it's how I would do it in Illustrator or Inkscape.